# Ubuntustudio application menu, games category

Tags: ubuntu-studio, appmenu, xdg

Since Ubuntustudio switched to the plasma-desktop with 20.10 we have a new organized application menu which divides the games category in subcategories.

This is nice if one install a lot of games. But it increases the number of clicks you need to launch a game. I install or play games only occasionally, so it makes more sense for me to have all games in the games category and not in any subcategory.

How can I change my menu to display all games in the games category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a file named `games.menu` with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN" "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/menu-1.0.dtd">
<Menu>
    <Name>Applications</Name>
    <Menu>
        <Name>Games</Name>
        <Directory>kf5-games.directory</Directory>
        <Menu>
            <Name>Arcade</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-noshow.directory</Directory>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <Name>Board</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-noshow.directory</Directory>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <Name>Card</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-noshow.directory</Directory>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <Name>Kidsgames</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-noshow.directory</Directory>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <Name>TacticStrategy</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-noshow.directory</Directory>
        </Menu>
        <Menu>
            <Name>Logic</Name>
            <Directory>ubuntustudio-noshow.directory</Directory>
        </Menu>
        <Include>
            <Category>Game</Category>
        </Include>
    </Menu>
</Menu>
```

Place this file in `/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/` for systemwide configuration or
in `~/.config/menus/applications-merged/` (you may need create this folder) for per-user configuration.

Nothing else to do, it will take a moment for the xdg-subsystem to update and then you will see the changes in the application menu.

I tested this with Ubuntustudio 20.10, 21.04 and 21.10.

This will definitely not work on earlier versions of Ubuntustudio since they come with the XFCE-desktop.